# Calling "document.getElementByID" in React Component vs. "ref"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to open a modal by changing the style properties of the modal, so it is visible. I works perfectly when I write a function like this:

```
modalAction(action) {
        switch (action) {
            case "open": {
                const modal = document.getElementById("login-popup");
                modal.style.opacity = 1;
                modal.style.visibility = "visible";
            }

        }
    }
```

Yet I have never seen react code like this. Insead I read a lot about refs that use Code like this:

```
<div className="login-popup" ref={(ref) => {this.loginPopup = ref}} id="login-popup">
```

But as far as I see it using refs will only alow me to access a virtual DOM elements in the same (or nested) components. The modal is a component of itself and is not nested it is calles in.

I could solve my problem using redux but writing a reducer-case as well as an action and producing an additional piece of state seems overkill for my sort of problem.

**How can I access the modals style properties the right way if the modal is neither nested nor in the same component where it is called from?** Thx

Comment: if the modal is a react component, you should use React.createPortal so you could call it where you need but render it where it needs to be rendered.

Comment: I would suggest not using style properties and instead use CSS classes to encapsulate the necessary styles to apply.

Comment: I agree with @Hitmands. The only 2 ways I see here are either by using a redux state, or by using a React Portal (if you want to do it React way).

Comment: But I don't really get it, though ... The problem is, that the button that I click to open the modal is outside of the Modal component. Rendering the to a different root with react Portal does not really allow me to access it in another way than to use document.getElementByID ... which changes nothing for the component that actually has to open the modal ...

Comment: Also I would really like to unserstand why the code using "getElementByID" is bad or so uncommon. It works and really seems to be a lot simpler then all the alternatives.